# Chartjs - Donut Chart label for small values not visible

Tags: label, pie-chart, chart.js

Values for my Chart range from 10 to 70000. Since 70000 is too large, small values are not visible in the chart and I cannot view its label on hovering over it. Is it possible to show all labels, without having to hover or any better solution for this. fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sanal_5/e6zdk6jt/4/

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/Sanal_5/e6zdk6jt/4/][1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could draw the legend for the pie chart by calling `generateLegend` on the created chart and add an event listen to highlight the segment when hovered over in the legend

```js
$(function() {
  var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

  var PieData = [{
    value: 70000,
    color: "#f56954",
    highlight: "#f56954",
    label: "Chrome"
  }, {
    value: 6000,
    color: "#00a65a",
    highlight: "#00a65a",
    label: "IE"
  }, {
    value: 4000,
    color: "#f39c12",
    highlight: "#f39c12",
    label: "FireFox"
  }, {
    value: 4000,
    color: "#00c0ef",
    highlight: "#00c0ef",
    label: "Safari"
  }, {
    value: 3000,
    color: "#3c8dbc",
    highlight: "#3c8dbc",
    label: "Opera"
  }, {
    value: 10,
    color: "#d2d6de",
    highlight: "#d2d6de",
    label: "Navigator"
  }];
  var pieOptions = {
    segmentShowStroke: true,
    segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
    segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
    percentageInnerCutout: 50,
    animationSteps: 100,
    animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
    animateRotate: true,
    animateScale: false,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true
  };
  var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas).Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);

  var helpers = Chart.helpers;
  var legendHolder = document.getElementById('graph-legend');
  legendHolder.innerHTML = pieChart.generateLegend();

  // Include a html legend template after the module doughnut itself
  helpers.each(legendHolder.firstChild.childNodes, function(legendNode, index) {
    helpers.addEvent(legendNode, 'mouseover', function() {
      var activeSegment = pieChart.segments[index];
      activeSegment.save();
      pieChart.showTooltip([activeSegment]);
      activeSegment.restore();
    });
  });
  helpers.addEvent(legendHolder.firstChild, 'mouseout', function() {
    pieChart.draw();
  });

  document.getElementById('graph-legend').appendChild(legendHolder.firstChild);

});
```

```css
.box-body,
#graph-legend {
  width: 50%;
  float: left
}
#graph-legend ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#graph-legend ul li {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 8px 2px 28px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
}
#graph-legend li span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
  <canvas id="pieChart" width="787" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="graph-legend"></div>
```

Comment: @SanalS if this solves your question you can mark it as the answer or wait for more responses if it doesn't

Comment: On adding a second Donut chart, the CSS for legend is not showing.