# Adding legend into a pie chart in chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I am using chart.js to add in a legend to my pie chart but because I am following this link, https://jsfiddle.net/red_stapler/9931gjh6/11/, to do it, I am unsure of how it works. Sorry I just started learning on how to create a pie chart so there are a lot of things I am still weak at.

I want in my legend where it shows red as number of danger zone, yellow as normal zone and green as safe zone.

Example something like this:
red color -> will say "300% are in danger zone"

I know that for chart.js I have to use something like this, but because it is quite different in the link that I used, I am unsure. So could someone help me? Thanks a lot

Originally:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        legendCallback: function(chart) {
            // Return the HTML string here.
        }
    }
});
```

So how to create the legend based on the jsfiddle?

Comment: Is [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221071/chartjs-donut-chart-label-for-small-values-not-visible) helpful to you

Comment: @SanalS this link helps a lot thanks! But may I know which part to change the size of the legend because it is showing really small

Comment: Good to know. I was just going combine your code with it for testing. Please upvote that question if that helped.

Comment: Yup done that, thanks for helping. Just asking do you know how to convert the chart into an image? Because I manage to only convert the chart to image but not the legend

Comment: Using this script,  $("#save-btn").click(function() {
        $("#pieChart").get(0).toBlob(function(blob) {
            saveAs(blob, "chart_1.png");
        });
});

Comment: I have converted it to image before, let me check

Comment: Thanks a lot, if possible could you post your image part with the legend together as an answer

Comment: sorry i couldn't convert the whole div to image. But i did found [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/) which does a similar case.

Comment: I found this, https://jsfiddle.net/x3vf9qv2/27/ but I am unsure of how to save 2 different id. As you can see in the previous comment, I said, it can only take 1 id, is there any way to also get graph-legend id?

Comment: you could find the parent div which contains both chart and legend and then convert that div into image

Comment: I tried that already and it gave me this error, Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).toBlob is not a function

Comment: You can't directly call toBlob on the div. You need to convert it to a canvas first. In [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/) I commented earlier, they are doing so. They are converting div to Canvas and then to image. Use the resources he used in this fiddle.

Comment: Yes... I was using canvas.. but it just return me with only the graph

Comment: Actually never mind that part, just asking why can't I convert the Doughnut chart to pie chart? I have change this part nothing is happening it still show the doughnut, var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas).Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);

Comment: To change Doughnut chart to pie chart change: `percentageInnerCutout: 50,` into `percentageInnerCutout: 0,`

Comment: Have you checked if only your chart is within the canvas. Legend might be generated outside of canvas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162143/discussion-between-blastme-and-sanal-s).